# How do I remove a relationship entirely using POI Word?

Tags: java, image, apache-poi, relationship, xwpf

Currently I'm attempting to load an existing document, remove all images, and re-add them. If anyone needs more details on why I'm doing this I'll be happy to provide it.

The problem I'm faced with is when I re-add the images the  tag shows "r1:embed" instead of "r:embed" to list the blip Id. This causes the "The picture can't be displayed" message to be displayed in the document. After going in and modifying the document.xml to replace all the instances of "r1:embed" to "r:embed" the pictures show up just fine.

I'm assuming this is because the relationship still exists in the document.xml.rels file after the images are removed. When the images are added back in, it uses the same images and rIds, but the  tag changes the schema to "r1" instead of keeping it at "r"

[a:blip snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdEEO.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

This is the code I'm using to remove images:

```
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(input);
    List<IBodyElement> elements = document.getBodyElements();
    for (IBodyElement element : elements) {
        if (element instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph) element;
            List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
            for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
                while (run.getCTR().getDrawingList().size() > 0) {
                    run.getCTR().removeDrawing(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also used the "removePict()" method, but that didn't remove the images from the document. I also tried using both removePict() and removeDrawing() with their corresponding while loops with no success at removing them from the relationships file entirely.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you doing the removal of the images?

Comment: Added the code I'm using.